# add fees to transacitons - customer will cover fees

Tags: paypal

we are going to integrate paypal to our system and I have a question about surcharge.

Is possible to add for example 4% to all transaction and thanks to it, customer will cover transaction fees? I've heard that paypal don't allow it but I'm not sure about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the merchant will have to bare the PayPal transactions fees. You could perhaps increase the price by a slight margin to cover the transaction fees if you would like.

Jeremy